# Capturar evento clic de un botón con MotionEvent

Tags: android

Tengo un botón que al dejarlo presionado empieza a grabar una nota de voz y al soltar el dedo detiene la grabación.

El problema está en que si a este botón le haces clic, es decir, lo tocas una vez con el dedo, el App se cierra.

Error que recibo:

> E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007 E/InputEventReceiver: Exception
>   dispatching input event. E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue
>   callback: handleReceiveCallback E/MessageQueue-JNI:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
>   at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)

**Código:**

```
private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 2;
private Button mRecordButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        // View
        mRecordButton = findViewById(R.id.recordButton);

        mRecordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                String[] permissions = {
                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
                };

                // Request the permission if needed
                if (!MyUtil.hasPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
                } else {
                    // TODO: Fix the crash when a single clic is performed
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            startRecording();
                            return true;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            stopRecording();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

He intentado haciendo `mRecordButton.setOnClickListener` pero no funciona, el App se sigue cerrando.

Cómo puedo capturar el clic para mostrar un mensaje diciendo "Debe dejar el botón presionado para grabar" ? o al menos evitar que el App se cierre cuando el botón recibe un clic.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Robert, busca en el LogCat la linea que indica "Caused by" ... Por lo pronto te comento que si estas agregando esta declaración: mRecordButton = findViewById(R.id.recordButton);  abajo de private Button mRecordButton; es incorrecto, revisa mi respuesta,saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys He buscado y no encuentro la línea que comentas.

Comment: Lo que agregaste es el código actual? @RobertGomez Asegyura que en el LogCat tengas seleccionada la opción "Show only selected application".

Comment: @Jorgesys así es, es tal cual como lo tengo ahora mismo. Funciona si dejas el dedo presionado pero, si haces 1 clic el App se cierra. El comportamiento que deseo es que cuando se hace 1 clic no pase nada, o al menos mostrar un mensaje al usuario avisando de que para grabar necesita dejar el dedo presionado.

Answer (score 0):

La obtención de las referencias de elementos como el botón debe realizarse dentro de `onCreate()`, después de cargar el layout que lo contiene mediante `setContentView()`.

Obten la referencia y configura el listener, revisa este ejemplo basado en tu código:

```
        private Button mRecordButton;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Obtiene botón!
            mRecordButton = findViewById(R.id.recordButton);     

            //define listener a botón.
            mRecordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            startRecording();
                            return true;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            stopRecording();
                            break;
                    }

                return false;
               }
           });


            ...
            ...
       }
```

Comment: Hola amigo, estoy consciente de lo que comentas y es de esa forma que tengo mi código, simplemente no lo puse en mi pregunta ya que consideraba eso innecesario o algo obvio pero, por lo visto puede llegar a confundir. Voy a editar mi pregunta agregando exactamente cómo tengo el código.